# Remove every special character from start of string and store it in a variable

Tags: python, string-interpolation

I am trying to build a Pig Latin translator. I want to remove all the characters on the start of a string and store them in a variable. I have already done it to the end, but for some reason when I try and do it the the start it messes up the word.

For example, when I input `*test*` it returns `*stteay*` when it should return `*esttay*`. Also if you put in `test*` it works fine. I have no clue why.

The funny thing is, that if I only put a special character to the end of the string it works fine! The two pieces of code for extracting the special chars are pretty much identical as well.

Here is the code:

```
def special_chars_check(text: str) -> bool:
return any(c for c in text if not c.isalnum() and not c.isspace())


def convert(stuff):
    words = stuff.split()
    output = ''
    for i in words:
        post_special_chars = ''
        reversed_temp = i[::-1]
        for c in reversed_temp:
            if special_chars_check(reversed_temp[0]):
                if special_chars_check(c):
                    post_special_chars = f'{post_special_chars}{reversed_temp[0]}'
                    reversed_temp = reversed_temp[1:]
                    i_temp = reversed_temp[::-1]
                else:
                    break
            
    if len(post_special_chars) == 0:
        i_temp = i
        
    pre_special_chars = ''
    normal_temp = i_temp
    for c in normal_temp:
        if special_chars_check(normal_temp[0]):
            if special_chars_check(c):
                pre_special_chars = f'{pre_special_chars}{normal_temp[0]}'
                normal_temp = normal_temp[1:]
                i_temp = normal_temp
            else:
                break
            
    if len(pre_special_chars) == 0:
        i_temp = i

    allcaps = False
    firstcaps = False
    if i.isupper():
        allcaps = True
    elif i[0].isupper():
        firstcaps = True
    i_temp2 = i_temp
    vowel_in = False
    for c in i:
        if c in 'aeiouAEIOU':
            vowel_in = True
    if i[0] in 'aeiouAEIOU' and vowel_in:
        if allcaps:
            output = f'{output} {pre_special_chars}{i_temp.upper()}WAY{post_special_chars}'
        elif firstcaps:
            temp_output = i.lower()
            temp_char2 = temp_output[0]
            temp_output = temp_output[1:]
            final_i_temp = f'{temp_char2.upper()}{temp_output}'
            output = f'{output} {pre_special_chars}{final_i_temp}way{post_special_chars}'
        else:
            output = f'{output} {pre_special_chars}{i_temp}way{post_special_chars}'
    elif i[0] not in 'aeiouAEIOU' and vowel_in:
        fulfilled = False
        for c in i:
            if not fulfilled:
                if c in 'aeiouyAEIOUY':
                    if allcaps:
                        output = f'{output} {pre_special_chars}{i_temp.upper()}AY{post_special_chars}'
                    elif firstcaps:
                        temp_output = i_temp.lower()
                        temp_char2 = temp_output[0]
                        temp_output = temp_output[1:]
                        final_i_temp = f'{temp_char2.upper()}{temp_output}'
                        output = f'{output} {pre_special_chars}{final_i_temp}ay{post_special_chars}'
                    else:
                        output = f'{output} {pre_special_chars}{i_temp}ay{post_special_chars}'
                    fulfilled = True
                else:
                    temp_char = i_temp2[0]
                    i_temp = f'{i_temp2[1:]}{temp_char}'
                    i_temp2 = i_temp
                    fulfilled = False
    else:
          output = f'{output} {i}'
try:
    output[1:]
except:
    return output
else:
    return output[1:]

while True:
    print(convert(input('Enter text: ')))
```

It would really help if someone could point out my mistake.

Thankyou!

Comment: You will have better luck if you explain to others exactly what you want your code to do instead of relying on people googling "Pig Latin"/ Also, the last `try... except... else` should be reindented.

Comment: @JustLearning My bad about the indenting. It didn't really require you to know what pig latin is. I did put an example up the top to help people. Basically all I want to know is why the first bit of code that moves the special characters around doesn't work the same as the other one (right below it).

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer... It was a silly little mistake. On line 63 `for c in i:` needed to be `for c in i_temp:` Thankyou to @JustLearning for the advice.